# How can I use mysqli_conect with docker-compose in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, docker-compose

I've got the following docker-compose script:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
        ports:
            - 80:80/tcp
            - 443:443/tcp
        environment:
            CERTBOT_EMAIL: owner@company.com
        links:
          - php
        volumes:
          - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
          - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
          - ./workspace:/var/www/html

    php:
        image: php:7.4-fpm
        links:
          - docker-mysql
        volumes:
          - ./workspace:/var/www/html/
          - ./php:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

    docker-mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: docker-mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=bla
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bla
          - MYSQL_USER=bla
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=bla
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

The issue I'm facing is the following:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in ...`

What can I do to get mysqli working? I already tried looking at the docu on Dockerhub, but haven't found anything which I understand.
I also already tried to run `docker-php-ext-install mysqli` inside the php container with no luck. It says the module is installed, however I can't see it activated when running phpinfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add mysqli extension in the Dockerfile for PHP.
You need to create Dockerfile and inside it use this command:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

In your docker-compose.yml specify the Dockerfile for PHP (instead of "image")

```
php:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Of course it is not complete Dockerfile, google "Dockerfile PHP 7.4 fpm example"